# Bokeh Server with 3 y axes doesn't plot,but does for 2 y axes.Why?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, multiple-axes

My objective is to plot live data on multiple y axes(different ranges). The following code worked with 2 y axes but when I added a 3rd one, the browser was just blank.An earlier basic bokeh plot with 4 y axes worked fine but this server version is not working.I dont know what mistake I am doing,please guide me.

The follwing code plots 2 temporary points then a 3rd permanent point. Uses 'patch' and 'stream' from ColumnDataSource to achieve this.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
import numpy as np

def plotcharts(source,x,a,b,c):
    fig=figure(y_range=(0, 500))
    fig.circle(source=source, x=x,y=a,size=12,color='red')

    fig.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=50)}
    fig.circle(source=source,x=x, y=b, size=12, color="blue", 
    y_range_name="foo1")
    fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo1"), 'left')

    # configure 3rd axis
    fig.extra_y_ranges = {"foo2": Range1d(start=0, end=25)}
    fig.circle(source=source, x=x, y=c, color="magenta", 
    y_range_name="foo2")
    fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo2"), 'right')

    return fig

count=(-1)
dct=dict(x=[],a=[],b=[],c=[])  
#Just a and b work fine but when 3rd axis c was added it doesnt !
source=ColumnDataSource(dct)
fig=plotcharts(source,'x','a','b','c') #c==3rd axis

def update_data():
    global count
    count=count+1
    y1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=500)
    y2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=50)
    y3 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=25) #y3==3rd axis

    if count%3==0:
        new_data = {
            'x': [count/3],
            'a': [y1],
            'b': [y2],
            'c': [y3]  #c==3rd axis
        }
        source.stream(new_data,rollover=20)

    else:
        l = len(df['a'])
        new_data = {
            'a': [(l - 1,y1)],
            'b': [(l - 1, y2)],
            'c': [(l - 1, y3)]  #c==3rd axis
        }
        source.patch(new_data)

curdoc().add_root(fig)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_data,1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these two lines in your code:

```
fig.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=50)}
[...]
fig.extra_y_ranges = {"foo2": Range1d(start=0, end=25)}
```

Bokeh doesn't try to do some special magic on setting these fields, so with the latter statement, you just override the former. Instead, you should just write one line:

```
fig.extra_y_ranges = {"foo1": Range1d(start=0, end=50), "foo2": Range1d(start=0, end=25)}
```